# Is there any way to modify or manage the startup processes in RHEL 7.4?

Tags: linux, rhel, linux-kernel, watchdog

I updated my kernel rpm from kernel version kernel-3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64 to kernel version kernel-3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64.After update, a process named **watchdogd with pid 49** is continuously running at the background.

I think this process is kernel invoked.

Is there any way to **rename kernel processes** or is there any way we can **manage the startup processes** in RHEL 7.4 ? I am unable to find any watchdogd.conf file or any watchdogd.service on my system.

Which script is responsible for **startup of these processes** and is there any way to change that script or **change the startup process name**?

Command Used:

**ps -ef | grep -i watchdogd**

Output:

**root 49 2 0 04:03 ? 00:00:00 [watchdogd]**

**root 1592 1563 0 04:04 pts/0 00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i watchdogd**

Comment: In general, or specifically for the watchdogd process?

Comment: Specifically for watchdogd process.

Comment: Why do you wish to rename the `watchdogd`  kernel thread?

Comment: One of my own service is also having same name that's why i want to either rename or disable kernel's watchdogd.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not a system service but a kernel thread. Documentation for the watchdog is [in the kernel source documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/watchdog/watchdog-kernel-api.txt). I don’t think you can easily rename without recompiling your own kernel.

Comment: Is it possible to stop execution of this thread during startup ??